# Trying to organize an array of structs in C

Tags: arrays, c, sorting, struct

I'm a relatively new programmer working with structs for the first time in C. Currently I'm tasked with organizing an array of structs based on an int contained within the struct. I have the merge sort algorithm implemented and working with an array of ints, but I am confused on how to sort the ints when they're within a struct.

So far I've tried making an array containing only the ints I'm concerned with. However, then the original array of struts isn't sorted, just the new integer array.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please get familiar with [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and in particular ask a question at all.  You should also show us your code if you want to get specific advice.

Comment: You can use the assignment operator with structs of the same type as you would any other type, e.g. structA1 = structA2, where you've typedef'd structA. You can't compare though, structA1 == structA2 is not valid c. You can reference an element x in structA1 with structA1.x and if you have a structA pointer struct_ptr->x. You can compare int elements of your structs with structA1.x >= structA2.x. Your sorting program should mostly work the same way as it does with int.

Comment: If you show us your code which sorts an array of `int` and if you show us the definition of your `struct`, then we can tell you which part of your code must be changed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Though not asked in a clear way, I guess your question is 'sorting an array of structures, with an int in the structure as the key'.
And there are other 'contents' in the structure but not the key.
If so, you should sort the struct instead of only the key.
Here is an example:

```
typedef struct
{
    int key;
    int other_value;
}ele;
#define SIZE 5
ele arr[SIZE];
void example_bubble_sort(void)
{
    int i; int j;
    for(i=0;i<SIZE;i++)
    {
        for(j=0;j<(SIZE-i - 1);j++)
        {
            if(arr[j].key > arr[j+1].key)
            {
                ele temp = arr[j];
                arr[j] = arr[j+1];
                arr[j+1] = temp;
            }
        }
    }
    return;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, this actually seems like it answers the question I had. Sorry for the confusion in the question’s description, I’ll try and at using better terminology in the future!

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming your struct looks like this and you have an array of the struct

```
typedef struct {
    int value;
} MyStruct;

MyStruct arr[] = {
        {10}, {7}, {8}, {5}, {2}
};
```

apply your sorting algorithm to arr[] where the each number in the array can be accessed by arr[i].value so you can use the numbers to sort the array